# JavaFX alert box on button click

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently working on my JavaFX ZOO project and I have a problem. I am showing all of my records in a TableView and one of the columns contains a delete button. It all works perfectly, but I want to have an alert box showing up after clicking that delete button, just for safety.

So my **delete button class** looks like this:

```
    private class ButtonCell extends TableCell<Record, Boolean> {
    final Button cellButton = new Button("Delete");

    ButtonCell(){

        cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

                Animal currentAnimal = (Animal) ButtonCell.this.getTableView().getItems().get(ButtonCell.this.getIndex());

                data.remove(currentAnimal);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if(!empty){
            setGraphic(cellButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, my **AlertBox class** looks like this:

```
public class AlertBox {

    public static void display(String title, String message){

        Stage window = new Stage();

        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setMinWidth(250);

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText(message);
        Button deleteButton = new Button("I'm sure, delete!");

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label,deleteButton);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();

    }

}
```

I want to make this so after i click "Delete" button, the alert box shows up, ask for permission, and after that the rest of the deletion code is being performed.

I also considered to add Alert instead of my AlertBox class, f.e: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/  (Confirmation Dialog)
but I have no idea how to implement it.

Any help would be great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will borrow code from the website you mentioned.

```
cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t){

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, a Confirmation Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("Are you ok with this?");

            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                Animal currentAnimal = (Animal) ButtonCell.this.getTableView().getItems().get(ButtonCell.this.getIndex());
                data.remove(currentAnimal);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow, great job! Thank You Chandler :)